# Conditionally style ALL html tags in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I have `<p>` tags in a React component for which I would like to align center  or left depending on a prop. Right now, I am writing the same condition for *each and every* `<p>` tag like so:

`<p align={this.props.someBoolean ? "center" : "left"}>`

Obviously I can't put this condition in an associated CSS file, but I would like to accomplish a similar result -- style the `<p>` tag once in a central location. Is this possible?

Comment: Just change `align` to `class`, conditionally changing the class on the `<p>` tag. Then your CSS can dynamically style it. Hooray!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add css rule to block wrapper:

```
<div style={{textAlign: this.props.someBoolean ? "center" : "left"}}> 
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    ----------
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [style-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-it) from npm then in your main component

> You should add Style tag in router component or this will apply only in the same component

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {
    someBoolean: true
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Style>
          {`
      .someClass {
          font-size: small;
          font-family: arial;
          background: #f1f1f1;
        }
      p { // this will apply on all p tag if you added in router component
          font-size: large;
          textAlign: ${this.state.someBoolean ? "center" : "left"}
      }
      input[type=text] {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
         `}
        </Style>
         <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/a" component={A} />
        <Route path="/b" component={B} />
        <Redirect to='/a' />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Main;
```

[image: Edit React-router-dom with style-it]